# Update object using only DbSet

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I'm trying to apply the unit of work pattern as described in [this blog](https://codefizzle.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/correct-use-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-asp-net-mvc/), but have bumped into the following problem: If I inject the associated DbSet into the repo only, e.g.

```
public ArticleRepository(DbSet<Article> articles)
{
   this.articles = articles;
}
```

then how do I update records or set their status to modified?

Before I used

```
public void Update(Article article)
{
   this.context.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

but with the new approach I don't have access to DbContext anymore. Neither DbSet.Add nor DbSet.Attach will work here, so how can I update the object in the context?

Comment: `IGenericRepository` should be totally by your design. You can add some method to set state for an entity there. That kind of interface really looks like a wrapper. So if possible try exposing the core part (DbContext, ...) via some other hidden interface. When needed you can always access to the core to perform some ***advanced*** task. As a wrapper, sometimes it cannot provide full operations as what you can do with core parts. To me that pattern is based much on the so-called ***wrapper***.

Comment: 1. You can access the context from the `DbSet`. 2. Don't inject the `DbSet`, inject the context itself and then set `this.articles` using the context. 3. Do you know why are you abstracting away the context at all? Entity Framework context is already having a built-in Unit Of Work mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

System.Data.Entity.Migrations.IDbSetExtensions contains the IDbSet extension AddOrUpdate`<TEntity`>. This will update the entity.

Some people like the advantage of not knowing whether they are adding a new entity or changing an existing one.

However, if you really want an error if you are updating an item that is not added yet, take a look at the [Source Code of IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17903547/)

Here you can see that the function first checks if the item exists and depending on the result adds or updates it as follows:

```
var existing = set.SingleOrDefault
    (Expression.Lambda<Func <TEntity, bool>> (matchExpression, new[]
        {parameter}));

if (existing != null)
{   // entity exists: update it
    foreach (var keyProperty in keyProperties)
    {
        keyProperty.Single().SetValue
            (entity, keyProperty.Single().GetValue (existing, null), null);
    }
    internalSet.InternalContext.Owner.Entry(existing)
        .CurrentValues.SetValues (entity);
}
else
{   // not existing entity: Add it
    internalSet.Add(entity);
}
```

If you don't want the AddOrUpdate, but really only an update, consider Creating your own Extension method for IDbSet. See [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)